# top of the page ribbon box in mdframed

Tags: mdframed

I would like to expect the `framebox` (like 1B) in the top of the each page when `exercise` environment is started to ending the `exercise` environment (i.e., page 2 and 3 only and not page 1, because exercise is started middle of the page 1). Please find the screenshot below:

![enter image description here][1]

My MWE IS:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[driver=none]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[tikz]{mdframed}
\geometry{
  paperwidth=190mm,
  paperheight=256mm,
  asymmetric,
  left=20mm,
  right=20mm,
  top=22.5mm,
  bottom=15mm,
  headsep=10.5mm,
  footskip=4mm,
  marginparsep=2mm,
  headheight=21pt
}
\usepackage[cam,a4,center,pdflatex]{crop}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{exercise}
\newenvironment{exercise}[1][]{
  \stepcounter{exercise}%
  \mdfsetup{%
    backgroundcolor=green,
    linecolor=blue,%
    linewidth=2pt,
    frametitlerule=true,
    frametitlerulewidth=2.5pt,
  }\relax
  \begin{mdframed}%
}{%
  \end{mdframed}%
}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Titlte}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{exercise}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{exercise}
\lipsum[6-14]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `tcolorbox` again:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[driver=none]{geometry}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\geometry{
  paperwidth=190mm,
  paperheight=256mm,
  asymmetric,
  left=20mm,
  right=20mm,
  top=22.5mm,
  bottom=15mm,
  headsep=10.5mm,
  footskip=4mm,
  marginparsep=2mm,
  headheight=21pt
}
\usepackage[cam,a4,center,pdflatex]{crop}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{exercise}[2][]{%
colback=green,
colframe=blue,
arc=0pt,
toprule=2.5pt,
bottomrule=2.5pt,
boxsep=0pt,left=2pt,right=2pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,
breakable,
enhanced jigsaw,
fonttitle=\fontsize{25}{17}\selectfont\bfseries,
title=\strut Exercise~\thetcbcounter: #2,
%grow to left by=-0.2in,
%enlarge left by=0.2in,
%enlarge right by=-0.4in,
   overlay middle and last={
           \checkoddpage
     \ifoddpage
     \node[anchor=north west,align=left,text width=1.5in,font=\Large\bfseries]
        at ([shift={(2ex,-0.55ex)}]frame.north east) (a) {\thetcbcounter};
     \begin{scope}[on background layer]
           \fill[green!30] (a.south west) to[bend left] (a.north west) -- +(2in,0) |- (a.south west);
     \end{scope}
     \else
     \node[anchor=north east,align=right,text width=1.5in,font=\Large\bfseries]
        at ([shift={(-2ex,-0.55ex)}]frame.north west) (b) {\hfill\thetcbcounter};
     \fi
         \begin{scope}[on background layer]
           \fill[green!30] (b.north east) to[bend left] (b.south east) -- +(-2in,0) |- (b.north east);
         \end{scope}
           },
    before=\vskip\itemsep\noindent
#1}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter Titlte}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{exercise}{}
\lipsum[1-12]
\end{exercise}
\lipsum[6-14]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice. I don't see any difference between `overlay middle` and `overlay last`, so you can save some typing with `overlay middle and last`.

Comment: I think `overlay middle and last` doesn't include the first segment, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Ignasi Yes, But I preferred the long version though. Easy to control. Discard my previous comment, it is meaning less. :)

Comment: @Harish: How to set `oddside` and `evenside` to display the values and also i have tried `fonttitle=\fontsize{15}{17}\selectfont` to increase the `fontsize`. But it's not working. how to achive this.

Comment: @Harish: If `exercise` is starting in `newpage` (not middle of the page) how to print the values in `marginpar`?

Comment: @Balaji You can't. There is no hook for that IIRC.